# Creating a data type class that has different implementations depending on size of given list in Java

Tags: java, types, tree, abstract-data-type

So I'm trying to create a data type class that has different configurations depending on the size of a list given in the main. It's a data type for house listings and the idea is if the number of house listings(size) is greater than 1000, I'd have the data type called SmartULS be implemented using a tree or AVL tree.

On the other hand, if it's smaller than 1000, let it be implemented using a hash table. The idea is to make sorting/get/set/removing faster depending on the size of the list given.

I've worked this out so far, but it's not working:

```
   public class houseListings<K,V> {

    protected TreeMap<K,V> tree = new TreeMap<>();
    protected AbstractHashMap<K,V> hashMap = new AbstractHashMap<K,V>();

    public void setHouseListings(size){
        int threshold = 1000;
        if (size >= threshold) {
             map = new AbtractMap<K,V>();
        }
        else
             map = new TreeMap<K,V>();

    }
}
```

Comment: Rewrite your code into something that can actually run, and update your question.

Comment: What is the error? Also, as a side note, I think there is a typo in the line `map = new AbtractMap<K,V>();`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason its not working is because

1. You have typos in your code
2. You are using the wrong types (like `AbstractHashMap`). You should use `HashMap` and `TreeMap`

Now, coming to the ideal way of choosing different 'strategies' you should consider using the [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). I've put together some code to help you visualize it.

```
    public static void main(String... args) {

        //... some code that reads/calculates threshold

        DataVolumneStrategy strategy;
        if (threshold >= 1000) {
            strategy = new HighVolumeStrategy();
        } else {
            strategy = new NormalStrategy();
        }

        //use map
        strategy.getMap();

    }

    interface DataVolumneStrategy {

        Map<K, V> getMap();

    }

    static class NormalStrategy implements  DataVolumneStrategy{

        @Override
        public Map<K, V> getMap() {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
    }

    static class HighVolumeStrategy  implements  DataVolumneStrategy {

        @Override
        public Map<K, V> getMap() {
            return new TreeMap<>();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the methods such as get/set/remove etc that I'll be using inside the DataVolumeStrategy? Do i just use an if statement inside those methods to solve that problem?

Comment: @lesterpierson123 are you referring the to `get`,`put` methods of the returned `Map`? If yes, this strategy is only to get you an apt implementation of the `Map` interface as per your needs. Once you have that, you can use it the way you want in your main method. If no, can you elaborate your question.